# Camel route logic / Output expectations

Tags: java, jaxb, apache-camel, marshalling, unmarshalling

Background:
I'm trying to unmarshal an xml file using jaxb and camel. I think I'm having a hard time with it because I don't know exactly what to expect filewise.

For example, I have:

```
from("file://C:/test.xml").unmarshal(jaxb).to("file://C:/testEnd.java");
```

With that, I'm expecting to see the result of the unmarshalling in the .java file (i.e. parameters and values from the xml file elements). However, when I run the program, nothing shows up in the .java file, but I don't receive any errors.

The same thing happens with marshalling. When I have a .java file as the from function and a .xml file in the to function, nothing happens.

For example, I have:

```
from("file://C:/test.java").marshal(jaxb).to("file://C:/testEnd.xml");
```

From this, I would expect to see values from my annotated java file appear in the xml file.

Question:
Is my expectation in both of these cases correct? Or is there something wrong with that logic?

Comment: I would skip jaxb and if possible use jacksonxml as explained here. Easier to use. http://camel.apache.org/jackson-xml.html , also you need to define a .jaxb file and define your jaxb class.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:
If in your code you want to save java object in the form of an xml and then again use that xml to retrieve the state of the java object saved earlier, we do marshalling and unmarshalling
1) Marshalling: convert java object to xml based and save it to file
Create a producerTemplate sending java object to the producerendpoint, marshal it against jaxb dataformat and it would be converted to xml using the pojo bean marked with XmlRootElement and referred as contextPath in jaxb tag.

```
public class ClientEight {

    @Produce(uri="direct:invoice")
    ProducerTemplate template;
public static void main(String rgs[]) throws InterruptedException{
AbstractApplicationContext ctx= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/camel-configTen.xml");
        InvoiceXml invoice= new InvoiceXml("fdf3443",3454, 435345.44f, "hfhfddfdg"); //any java object we are passing
    ClientEight client = (ClientEight) ctx.getBean("client");
Object xmlObj= client.template.requestBody(invoice);
        System.out.println(xmlObj);
}
```

Above is a client code which u are using to send java object to a producer endpoint and since u are using template.requestBody, u are getting back the object returned.

```
<camel:camelContext>
        <camel:dataFormats>
            <!-- path to jaxb annotated class -->
            <camel:jaxb id="invoiceJaxb" contextPath="com.java.bean"
                prettyPrint="true" />
        </camel:dataFormats>
        <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="direct:invoice" />
            <camel:marshal ref="invoiceJaxb" />
            <camel:log message=" ${body}" />
            <camel:to uri="file://src/resources?fileName=One.xml"/>
        </camel:route>
    </camel:camelContext>
```

This would be your camel config file. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I define what the jaxb and uri (direct:invoice) are? Do I do that in the pojo?

Comment: Direct:invoice is an endpoint created by u on which u r sending a message through producertemplate as shown in clientEight class code. U don't need to do any other config., jaxb is again a component already defined in camel. Please refer to camel cookbook, it's a nice book

Answer (score 0):

The `file` component take a directory, and process all files in this directory. it doesn't handle file by default, you have to use options, or the stream component.

see http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

> **Only directories**
>
> Camel supports only endpoints configured with a
>   starting directory. So the directoryName must be a directory. If you
>   want to consume a single file only, you can use the fileName option,
>   e.g. by setting fileName=thefilename. Also, the starting directory
>   must not contain dynamic expressions with ${ } placeholders. Again use
>   the fileName option to specify the dynamic part of the filename.